# Running PIXI.js from a CDN

Tags: pixi.js

i'm trying to run the latest PIXI.js release inside Codepen. Wether is use the GUI or add a script tag to the head. When I setup a new PIXI application with:

```
const app = new PIXI.Appliction({})
```

I get an error

`PIXI is not defined.`

Any ideas plese.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the wrong CDN pakcage. If you are adding a script tag to the head of your HTML document, you need to use the browser package

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/6.5.4/browser/pixi.min.js" integrity="sha512-MLJM72M8frjnFXEvWn3NaVkrSxlDnbRK/Iwyr7loPca+13SdS9B5sNLHoIkDxfPOndP8WReNdwGLxisYUapc7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

otherwise, import directly from your script file eg index.js using the mjs link

```
import * as PIXI from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/6.5.4/browser/pixi.min.mjs'
```